# How to show notice if user update account is not successfull( devise gem )?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, overriding

I overrided a little devise gem to allow user change some details with or without account depends on situation.

I don't want to use devise error messages, because I'm using jQuery validation plugin.

**I want to show some notice error, when some devise errors exists, but I can't get where I need to put flash[:error].**

Here is my update action:

```
def update

self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
# custom logic
if params[:user][:password].present?
  result = resource.update_with_password(params[resource_name])
else
  result = resource.update_without_password(params[resource_name])
end

# standart devise behaviour
if result
  if is_navigational_format?
    if resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) && resource.pending_reconfirmation?
      flash_key = :update_needs_confirmation
    end
    set_flash_message :notice, flash_key || :updated
  end
  sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
  respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
 else
   if params[:user][:password].present?
    clean_up_passwords resource
    render "edit_user/edit_password"
    end
  end
```

So, can someone help me with this ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jquery validation have you enabled this on your views by doing something similar `<%= form_for @user, :validate => true,  do |f|%>`

**Update**
You could do something somewhat similar to this

```
def update_password
    @user = current_user    
    @current_password = params[:user][:current_password]
    @password = params[:user][:password]

    if @user.valid_password?(@current_password)
      if @current_password == @password
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
        flash[:error] = "Current password cannot be the same as your new password."
      else
        if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
          redirect_to login_path
          flash[:success] = "Password has been changed."
        else
          redirect_to user_path(@user)
          flash[:error] = "Didn't save contact an administrator."
        end
      end
    else
        redirect_to user_path(@user)
        flash[:error] = "Current password is incorrect."
    end
  end
```

Providing you add the top bit I suggested into your view and have installed Jquery validation correctly this should work

Comment: I mean, when submit is failing  after submit, for example current password is wrong, I want to show flash[:error]. Or do you know can I check current password using jQuery validatior ?

Comment: Djj, excuse me, your code didn't show any notices. Maybe, I will be checking current password using jQuery validatio plugin ? I'm already checking email uniqueness, can you help me with method which will be checking current password ?

Comment: I inserted it in my edit_password action, not in update action in registrations controller.